# How does AWS DynamoDB count read units for Query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am working on a table, in which every item is approx. 3KB in size.

Now as per the docs, the `read units` are calculated in **4s** - i.e. For every item less than 4 kb, it would be counted as 4KB, and occupy 1 read unit.

---

Let's say i have a table of `100` items, of `3kb` each in size (total table = `300kb`). I do a query, in which `50` items satisfy under the query condition, and they are returned to me.
Now, will the read units be counted like : `50 items` of `3kb size (rounded to 4kb)` = `200kb` = `200/4 = 50 read units` ?

Any help is appreciated! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should clarify the issue:

- [Capacity Units Consumed by Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.CapacityUnits)

> DynamoDB calculates the number of read capacity units consumed **based on item size**, not on the amount of data that is returned to an application.

When you do the query, you can specify a parameter `ReturnConsumedCapacity` to get the number of read capacity units consumed:

> TOTAL — The response includes the **aggregate number of read capacity units consumed**.

It also depends if you use eventually consistent reads (by default for query) or strongly consistent:

- for **eventually consistent** reads (1 unit is 2 reads): 200 / 4 / 2 = **25 units**
- for **strongly consistent** reads (1 unit is 1 read): 200 / 4 / 1 = **50 units**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you read 50 items of 3K each with **strongly consistent** reads, the cost will be 50 units. If you do **eventual consistent** reads, the answer will be half - 25 units.

However, there is another important cost issue you should be aware of, if you are not already. You mentioned you actually have 100 items, but only retrieving half of them by using a "query condition". DynamoDB actually has two types of "conditions" on queries. One of them are called **key conditions** (`KeyConditions` or `KeyConditionExpression`) and the other is post-query **filters** (`QueryFilter` or `FilterExpression`). If you use key conditions, you will only pay for the retrieved items - as you hoped. But if you use filtering, you will pay for all items, not just for the retrieved items. So in your example you would be paying 100 units instead of 50.

Comment: Thanks @nadav! Yes, I didn't know the `filter` point yet - Thanks! :)